# Unable to get property 'apiName' of undefined or null reference

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-recordviewform

I'm currently struggling with a strange error message in my Aura component, any kind of pointers or further debugging ideas would be most welcome! Thanks in advance!
So the setup is:

- A custom object (Risk__c) has a lookup relationship to Parent
  (Account).
- The number of risks related to the parent depend on the
  rating of the Account (basically if rating = 'Hot', then number of
  risks is reduced by 1).
- There's a before update Account trigger that
  takes care of the latter.
- The aura component is just a list of risks attached to the account, grouped by year.
- the RiskManagement apex controller provides data in the following format (wrapped object):`List<WrapRiskYear>`
- WrapRiskYear is also a wrapped object and contains a `Map<Integer,List<WrapRisk>>`
- WrapRisk is another (last) wrapped object that contains: the `Risk__c` object + a `boolean` flag if it's
  updateable or not.
- Aura component consists of 3 sub-components:
- Risk Tab (embedded on the record page, serves as the parent)
- Risk List (iterates over each year in `List<WrapRiskYear>`)
- Risk Item (iterates over each risk object in that year
- Once the Account record changes, an LDS `force:recordData` component listens for `recordUpdated` events
  and re-initializes the parent component, to refresh the list of risks.

Ok done with the setup.
Now when I update the account rating to 'Hot', the trigger deletes the link between account and Risk__c for one of the risks, and the list of risks (parent component) on the Account record page should refresh.

While I did get the component to refresh successfully, unfortunately I'm also seeing a bunch of errors thrown by the browser (the ones in the subject).

The same happens if I reverse the order and set the rating back to 'Hot', the trigger re-adds the risk back to account and the errors happen on component re-initialization. 
One particular thing I noticed is that the error seems to correlate with the new amount of risks. (occurs 3 times on Account rating update to Hot, and 4 times on Account update to Cold)

[image: Initial list of risks]
[image: Editing account to change the rating]
[image: Changing Acc rating from Cold to Hot]
[image: hot]
[image: Error occurred]
In IE the error shows without the popup, but still seen in console
[image: In IE the error shows without the popup, but still seen in console]

Here's the code:
Controller:

```
public with sharing class RiskMgmtController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<WrapRiskYear> getRiskData(Id recordId, String sObjectName){
    Map<Integer,List<WrapRisk>> wrapRisksObjs = new Map<Integer,List<WrapRisk>>();
    switch on sObjectName {
        when 'Account' {
            List<Risk__c> risks = getAccRisks(recordID);
            for(Risk__c r : risks){
                Integer year = (r.YearCompleted__c != NULL) ? r.YearCompleted__c.intValue() : Date.today().year();
                if(!wrapRisksObjs.containsKey(year)){
                    wrapRisksObjs.put(year, new List<WrapRisk>());
                }
                WrapRisk riskObj = new WrapRisk();
                riskObj.risk = r;
                riskObj.isUpdateable = (Schema.sObjectType.Risk__c.isUpdateable() && r.YearCompleted__c!= NULL);
                wrapRisksObjs.get(year).add(riskObj);
            }
        }
        when else {
            //nothing yet
        }
    }
    List<WrapRiskYear> wrapRisksObjsList = new List<WrapRiskYear>();
    for(Integer year : wrapRisksObjs.keySet()){
        WrapRiskYear riskListObj = new WrapRiskYear();
        riskListObj.year = year;
        riskListObj.risks = wrapRisksObjs.get(year);
        wrapRisksObjsList.add(riskListObj);
    }
    return wrapRisksObjsList;
}
//wrapper classes
public class WrapRisk{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Risk__c risk{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean isUpdateable{get; set;}   
}
public class WrapRiskYear{                
    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer year{get; set;}  

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<WrapRisk> risks{get; set;}
}

private static List<Risk__c> getAccRisks (Id recordId) {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, YearCompleted__c FROM Risk__c WHERE Account__c =:recordId order by YearCompleted__c DESC];
}
```

}

Account Trigger

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update) {
for(Account acc: Trigger.New){
    if(acc.Rating == 'Hot'){
        Risk__c riskToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Name, Parent__c, Account__c FROM Risk__c WHERE Parent__c =:acc.Id AND Name = 'A' LIMIT 1];
        riskToUpdate.Account__c = NULL;
        update riskToUpdate;
    }else{
        Risk__c riskToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Name, Parent__c, Account__c FROM Risk__c WHERE Parent__c =:acc.Id AND Account__c = NULL LIMIT 1];
        riskToUpdate.Account__c = acc.Id;
        update riskToUpdate;
    }
}
```

}

Risk Management Tab component (Parent component)

```
<aura:component controller="RiskMgmtController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="risksData" type="Object[]"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="accountService"
recordId="{!v.recordId}"
recordUpdated="{!c.doInit}"
fields="Name"/>

<lightning:card iconName="custom:custom60" title="Risks Identified" class="slds-is-relative">
    <div class="slds-list_vertical slds-has-dividers_top-space">
        <ul>
            <lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.risksData}" var="yearData">
                    <lightning:accordionSection name="{!yearData.year}" label="{!yearData.year}">
                        <c:RiskItemLst yearData="{!yearData}"/>
                    </lightning:accordionSection>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:accordion>
        </ul>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
<lightning:spinner aura:id="spinner" variant="brand" size="medium" alternativeText="Loading Risks"/>
```

Risk Management Tab component controller:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
    if (changeType === "ERROR") {}
    else if (changeType === "LOADED") {
        helper.h_doInit(component, event);
    }
        else if (changeType === "REMOVED") {}
            else if (changeType === "CHANGED") {
                helper.h_doInit(component, event);
            }
}
```

})

It's helper:

```
({
h_doInit : function(component, event) {
    var spinner = component.find("spinner");
    $A.util.removeClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
    var action = component.get("c.getRiskData");
    action.setParams({
        recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
        sObjectName: component.get("v.sObjectName")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        var result = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.risksData", result);
        $A.util.addClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

First Nested Risk List component (Risk Data by Year):

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="yearData" type="Object"/>

<ul class="slds-list_vertical slds-has-dividers_top-space">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.yearData.risks}" var="item">
        <li class="{!item.isUpdateable ? 'slds-list__item' : 'slds-list__item slds-theme--shade'}">
            <c:RiskItem riskItem="{!item.risk}" isUpdateable="{!item.isUpdateable}"/>
        </li>
    </aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

The second nested Risk Item component (Actual risks - Risk__c):

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="riskItem" type="Risk__c"   />
<aura:attribute name="isUpdateable" type="Boolean" default="false"/>    
<lightning:recordViewForm aura:id="viewForm"  recordId="{!v.riskItem.Id}" objectApiName="Risk__c" density="Comfy">
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name"/>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: is Risk__c object is part of managed package?

Comment: Just a note on formatting, the > and < characters are treated as HTML so when you do something like `Map<Id, SObject>` make sure to wrap it in the code tag or to use the escaped &lt; &gt;

Comment: @ManjotSingh, not in a managed package, it can be any related object in fact.

Comment: As per error is on `lightning:recordViewForm`, Please debug your `c:RiskItem` component problem may on that component,put the check if recordid not null. Is Risk__c object is private or public ? are you logged in as admin? check the access of Risk__c  to currently logged in user